# Webbrowser Control not Working with Flash Object

Tags: c#

For some reason my webbrowser control isn't working. I've tried using it on a a different project, then I restarted my computer, and it still isn't working. What is happening is that when I load a flash object, it gets stuck loading at 70%, and no matter what I do, it stays at 70%, it doesn't even load at all anymore. So what I need to do is somehow reset the webbrowser's defaults before I used it. Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Does the site work if you just run the site in IE instead of through the WebBrowser control?

Comment: I have done the exact same thing with an Internet Explorer webbrowser, and it works on there.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".